# Cancel Database Take Offline

Tags: sql-server-2005

I accidentally tried to take offline a DB via the context menu command > Tasks > Take Offline.

The process is ongoing now and no new connection can be made.

How do I cancel this process?

Comment: -1 for answering your own question 3 minutes after posting. Pleasey do more thorough research before asking questions.

Comment: I can understand both sides, but it's not a strongly discouraged behavior - http://serverfault.com/questions/6599/is-it-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-question

Comment: @Ernie actually "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions" as per http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer using [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx).

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```